Laravel override package translation not working on main project
I'm developing a laravel package and I'm testing translation overriding from this package to the the main project but strings are not overrided.
In the package service provider i set this:
$this->publishes([
            "{$this->rootDir}/lang" => base_path('lang/vendor/velzonui'),
        ], 'velzonui-translations');

and then i run this command:
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=velzonui-translations --force

and the package lang folder is copied to the main project lang folder but if I try to change a string label under the overrided translation file this is not overridden and I still see the transalation string from package.
this is my project folders structure.
enter image description here
I try to clear the caches with this command but without success:
php artisan cache:clear
